# MDX Calculated Members with Named Set

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

I've a calculated member named CWTD (Current Week To Date) Sales and to get this working I need to pass a named set Yesterday.

Is it possible to include the named set into the Calculated Member so that I don't have to pass the named set in my select statement?

The reason I'm asking this as Power View doesn't show Named Set in field list.

Example:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CWTD Sales Test]
 AS Sum(
            PeriodsToDate(
                [Date].[NZLC Date].[NZLC Week],
                [Date].[NZLC Date].CurrentMember
            ),  
            [Measures].[Net Sales - Gross for IK]
        )
select 
  [Measures].[CWTD Sales Test] on columns,
  NON EMPTY [Product].[Product].[Product Group] on rows
from [Daily Sales]
where 
  Tail(NonEmpty([Date].[NZLC Date].[Day].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Gross Sales]),1)
```

Is there anyway I can include the where part into my calculated member?

Comment: this `Tail(NonEmpty([Date].[NZLC Date].[Day].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Gross Sales]),1)` returns 1 day but your calculated member is for Current Week To Date .... so what is the point of the `WHERE` clause in your script? Why can't you just delete the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2):

Since your WHERE criteria represents the last day of your Gross Sales that has any data, you should simply use that tuple instead of .CurrentMember:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CWTD Sales Test]
 AS Sum(
            PeriodsToDate(
                [Date].[NZLC Date].[NZLC Week],
                Tail(NonEmpty([Date].[NZLC Date].[Day].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Gross Sales])).ITEM(0)
            ),  
            [Measures].[Net Sales - Gross for IK]
        )
select 
  [Measures].[CWTD Sales Test] on columns,
  NON EMPTY [Product].[Product].[Product Group] on rows
from [Daily Sales]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your query returning the below error:  CellOrdinal 0
VALUE #Error Query (3, 13) The PERIODSTODATE function expects a member expression for the 2 argument. A tuple set expression was used.
FORMATTED_VALUE #Error Query (3, 13) The PERIODSTODATE function expects a member expression for the 2 argument. A tuple set expression was used.

Comment: Try to change `TAIL( ... , 1)` to `TAIL( ... ).ITEM(0)` as seen in my example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm having issue with one more calculated member. I'm trying to create a calculation that returns Rolling Last 13 weeks Sales and the code is as below: 

WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Rolling Last 13 Weeks Sales] AS 
    Head(
      Tail
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Date].[NZLC Date].[NZLC Week].MEMBERS
         ,[Measures].[Gross Sales]
        )
       ,14
      )
     ,13
    ) 

I'm getting the following error:
VALUE #Error The function expects a string or numeric expression for the argument. A tuple set expression was used.

Answer (score 2):

@Dan has answered your question but just as an alternative:

```
WITH 
SET [Yesterday] AS
  Tail(
    NonEmpty(
      [Date].[NZLC Date].[Day].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Gross Sales]
    )
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[CWTD Sales Test] AS
  SUM(
    WTD([Yesterday].ITEM(0).ITEM(0))  
     ,[Measures].[Net Sales - Gross for IK]
  )
SELECT 
  [Measures].[CWTD Sales Test] ON 0,
  NON EMPTY [Product].[Product].[Product Group] ON 1
FROM [Daily Sales];
```

Comment: You forgot to give the second parameter to the `TAIL` function.

Comment: @whytheq, Thanks for you post. I already have a named set for yesterday but named sets are not visible in Power View. I would like to include the name set inside the Calculated member that Dan did. But this is complaining about the function PeriodToDate.